# How to edit KDE suspend settings via command line, without X session?

Tags: command-line, terminal, kde

I'm using KDE and I want to change system sleep timeout. It should be a part of a system bootstrap script (i.e. I want to automate it), so I'd like to know how can I manipulate KDE configs from command line.

I've found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/803629/how-do-i-programmatically-disable-the-kde-screen-locker), but the answer only works inside an X session, and I'd like to execute the script over ssh.

I suppose the config files are there somewhere, but I only found screen locking config in `.config`.

Comment: These are regular text files, so any text editor will do (`sed` from a script, or `vim`/`nano` in a terminal).

Comment: @xenoid ok, but I have trouble finding appropriate ones. I've updated question.

Comment: I listed 3 in my comment, available in the repos of any distro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not state which version of KDE you are using. User config files have been moved around between releases. In earlier releases, a lot was in `~/.kde` or `~/.kde4` while more recently `~/.config` is the standard directory.

With plasma 5.13 from KDE Neon, [Power devil](https://userbase.kde.org/Power_Devil) uses `~/.config/powermanagementprofilesrc`.

#### A general solution to find a config file:

1. Make a git repo (`git init`) in the directory you suspect the config files might be in (including its children)
2. Add everything to the repo (`git add .`)
3. Make a commit (`git commit`)
4. Make the change you want via GUI (e.g. System Settings)
5. Check where and what has changed (`git diff`)

You can remove the git repo with `rm -rf .git` when you are done. If you added a very big directory (like homedir) in step 1, then you might want to add some cache directories or other spontaneously changing false leads to the `.gitignore` file.

Also, you might want to bookmark https://userbase.kde.org/KDE_System_Administration for help on the location and syntax of config files.

Answer (score 0):

Though this question was already answered well by @Hmpf, there is one thing I'd like to add as an option for those who do not wish to use Git as the method to find the config file.

Step 1: Modify the setting you want to find & note the time you made the modification at
Step 2: Open a terminal and cd to `~/.config` (that is, for current versions of KDE)
Step 3: Run the list files command with the `-l` flag and `grep` for the current date

```
ls -l | grep "MMM DD"
```

Then just look for the timestamp that matches when you modified the setting.